# Yaakov Avinu wearing teffilin

Tags: torah-study

Where is it mentioned that Yaakov Avinu wore teffilin?

Is it something from Kabbalah, or something more drush?

Comment: Why do you think that is ever mentioned?

Comment: @DoubleAA from this (https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379348/jewish/Rings-Speckles-and-Spots.htm) and other articles,  i also remember learning it in yeshivah. and specifically that the sticks only carried holiness while being used for the mitzvah, after which, they retained no holy value.

Comment: כענין שבזוהר הקדש שיעקב קיים במקלות אשר פצל סוד התפילין,

Comment: @Chatzkel can you please put your response in the "answer" zone, and please try to include a citation i can explore further.

Comment: The Reishis Chochmah writes it in Shaar Kedushah. Bli Neder I will write it into an answer shortly.

Comment: @TheTargum it is a quote from the Shem mishmuel I had in the previous answer to you other question

Answer (score 1):

The [Reishis Chochmah](https://www.sefaria.org/Reshit_Chokhmah%2C_Gate_of_Holiness.6.83?vhe=Hamesorah_Publishers,_Jerusalem_2005&qh=%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F) quotes the Tana Debi Eliyahu and explains that "[the man sought to kill Yaakov](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), but had no power, since Yaakov was wearing tefillin on his head [...]":

> ובתנא דבי אליהו אמר על פסוק ויותר יעקב לבדו ויאבק איש עמו, אמרו ז"ל מלמד שרצה להרגו, ולא היה בו כח מפני שיעקב אבינו היה מזוין תפילין בראשו ובזרועו וציצית בבגדו, הדא הוא דכתיב וירא כי לא יכול לו ויגע וגו

See Pardes Yehudah by Rabbi Yehudah Zvulun Klitnick [(Parashas Vayishlach, 5777, year 6 #285: Tefillin at night? Only for Yaakov Avinu!)](https://www.antiqueseforim.com/Vayishlach%20English%205777.pdf)